# C# Get iFrame source within the current webrequest

Tags: c#

So I was wondering how I would get the source of an iFrame within the Page Source of the webrequest that has been made.

Example of what I mean:

```
string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); // Sets the string Text to the source of the page.
```

Now the string text holds the source of the page.
And within that page of the source is

```
Authenticator
</h3>
</div>
<div class="RaggedBoxContainer"><div class="RaggedBoxBg"><div class="RaggedBoxTop"></div><div class="RaggedBoxContent">
<iframe src="https://secure.runescape.com/m=totp-authenticator/a=13/c=zBsBJTw2E0M/accountinfo" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div><div class="RaggedBoxBottom"></div></div></div>
</div>
```

And I need it to read the source of the iFrame which is:

```
<h2 class="accountSettingsTitle">RuneScape Authenticator is enabled</h2>
<p>Your account is protected from hijackers. You will need your code generator each time you log in to RuneScape.</p>
<p>It's also really important to keep your email account secure. <a target="_top" href="https://support.runescape.com/hc/en-gb/articles/207258145">Find out how to do this.</a>
<p>You can <a target="_top" href="cape.com/m=totp-authenticator/a=13/c=zBsBJTw2E0M/disableTOTPRequest">disable</a> Authenticator - but remember this will make your account much less secure.</p>
```

How would I do that?
I know that in the webbrowser it will be:

```
foreach (HtmlElement elm in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe"))
{
     string src = elm.GetAttribute("src");
     if (src != null && src != "")
     {
          string content = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(src); //or using HttpWebRequest
          MessageBox.Show(content);
     }
}
```

Please help me out im confused.

Comment: why not get it using javascript?

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: document.getElementById("iframe_id").src

Comment: thats not possible with webrequest that is why I am posting.